# How to update Subversion externals

Tags: svn, branch, svn-externals

We have several subversion repositories: one for common code and one for each top level project.  The top level projects have a svn:external link to the trunk of the common repository.

Before we build a release of a project we create a branch of the top level project and also create a parallel branch in the common repository.

How can we automatically ensure the svn:external property in the branched top level project points to the parallel branch in the common directory - currently it will be pointing to "trunk" in the common respository.  We are currently having to manually edit this in the branched project.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you, you want to make sure that `foo` and `bar` share the same branch. `foo` is your master project and has an `svn:externals` on it somewhere pointing to `bar`. When you branch `foo`, you want to make sure `bar` is using the same branch. The only way to ensure that is to create your repository with the `tags` and `branches` directories at the root of your repository instead of at the root of the project (like most sites do).

Then you can use relative external references to point from the `foo` directory that contains the `svn:external` back to `bar`. Also, if you tag foo and bar with the same tag, foo and bar will maintain their relationship:

```
$ svn propset svn:externals ../../bar common
```

If your branches were at the root of your repository, then the `common` directory will be pointing to the same branch for `foo` as it is on `bar`.

The big problem with `snv:externals` is that if you're not careful, you're pointing to an ever changing version of the directory you're linking to. Let's say someone did this:

```
$ svn propset svn:externals /projects/bar/trunk common
```

in my `foo` project. I do a release and copy `foo` to a tag. However, the `common` directory that I've tagged will be modified when someone updates `bar/trunk`. This makes it almost impossible to rebuild `foo`.

When I use `svn:externals`, I always make sure I'm linking to either a tagged version of `bar`, or a specific revision, and if I am linking to a specific revision, I also peg my URL to that revision in case someone decides to delete the directory I'm linking to my `svn:externals` property.

There's nothing in Subversion that will automatically update your `svn:externals` properties, but you can search for all svn:externals on a directory tree by using

```
$svn propget -v -R svn:externals .
```

I've found that `svn:externals` usually ends up being a bigger pain than it's worth.

Instead, I simply store the built object of `bar` or a zipped up copy of the source in my release repository, and as part of my build procedure, I copy the object or zipped source out of my release repository.

I use Maven site repositories like Nexus or Artifactory as my release repository even if I am not doing a Maven project or even working in a Java based project. The local Maven repository provides all the tools you need to upload and download your dependent packages, plus Maven has the concept of *release* repository -- where the code never changes -- and a *snapshot* repository where you're planning on releasing the code, but it could change. This is helpful if you suspect that `bar` could change because of stuff you need in `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments.  However we could not rearrange our repositories so we have written a batch file that is run when we wish to branch for a release.  The batch file does the branch and updates the svn:externals to point to the parallel branch in the common repository.